# Form submit button not working in bootstrap modal window

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, post, submit

I have been trying to make this work but the submit button is not working at all.

The bootstrap modal window I am using is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="search" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
            <h4><span class="fa fa-search"></span> Search Anything...</h4>
        </div>          
        <form name='searchdata' action="webarch/search.php" method="post" id="form1">
        <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="input-with-icon success-control"> 
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form1Amount" name="searchvalue" placeholder="Search in users or #hashtags"><br/>
                    <button type="submit" name='user_search' form="form1" id="user_search" value='user' class="btn btn-danger btn-cons"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> User</button>
                    <button type="submit" name='tag_search' form="form1" value='tag' class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> Tags</button>

                </div>  
        </div>          
        </form> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I click the submit buttons, nothing happens and the form doesn't post the values.
Let me know how to make this work.

Comment: None of the submit buttons work?

Comment: yup. Both of them are not working. I m still not able to find a solution for it as there seems to be no issue

Comment: Is it just not submitting or submitting the whole form that the modal resides in?

Comment: It is not submitting the form I suppose. Because I initially tried the same code without the modal window and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this using javascript. It worked for me:

```
 <form name='searchdata' id="search_form" action="search.php" method="get">
                <div class="input-with-icon success-control">  
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form1Amount"     name="searchvalue" placeholder="Search in users or #hashtags"><br/>
                </div>  
                <button onclick="form_submit()" name='user_search' value='user' class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> User</button>
                <button onclick="form_submit()" name='tag_search' value='tag' class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> Tags</button>           
        </form> 

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function form_submit() {
    document.getElementById("search_form").submit();
   }    
  </script>
```

Comment: It worked. I was thinking of using javascript. Great. Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: But why? A little explanation would be helpful.

Comment: this oddly worked for me too, but I am also interested to know the reason why this does and any implications if this step is used.

Comment: I am having same issue and worked but i don't know how :D

Comment: Surely if we must resort to javascript `<button onclick="this.form.submit()"… >` is sufficient, without the `form_submit()` function.

Comment: document.getElementById('form').submit() ,form is id of form tag.this work

Comment: @showdev I think this is because the modal gets detached from the dom and moved when the modal is shown.

Answer (score 15):

Submit button is not in the form. Place form="modal-details" to the button, which is form id. You should not have data-dismiss="modal" on submit button, which is a bootstrap handler for closing the modal box. It is working for me.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="filterModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Client Filter</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Client" method="get" id="modal-details">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Branch:</label>
                        <select asp-for="NetworkUnitId" class="custom-select form-control">
                            <option value="0">All</option>
                            @foreach (var client in classifierService.GetClients())
                            {
                                <option value="@client.Id">@client.Name</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="modal-details">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Except in the example, the OP _did_ have the buttons in the form, and in my case I can find the button in the debug console and execute `button.form.submit()` which works, which should mean that clicking on the button would also work. You're also correct that `data-dismiss="modal"` will prevent submission (the modal is closed before the submit event), but OP doesn't have that in the example, either.
It appears bootstrap is overriding the default click handler.

Answer (score -1):

You have not mentioned modal-content here. I think that's why you may be getting the error.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#search" data-toggle="modal" name="button">modal</button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="search" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="modal-title">
          <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
          <h4><span class="fa fa-search"></span> Search Anything...</h4>
        </div>
      </div>

    <form name='searchdata' action="webarch/search.php" method="post" id="form1">
      <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="frm-group" action="index.html" method="post">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <input type="text" name="" value="">
                  <button type="submit" name='user_search' form="form1" id="user_search" value='user' class="btn btn-danger btn-cons"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> User</button>
                  <button type="submit" name='tag_search' form="form1" value='tag' class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> Tags</button>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```