# Bootstrap - Modal's submit button not working

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686089/form-submit-button-not-working-in-bootstrap-modal-window) but still the submit button won't work. I've recycled my code from the previous PHP I've worked but this time it isn't working, it just redirect me to my `index.php` page.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="post" id="form1" action="actions/add_lab_test.php" class="form-horizontal row-border">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h4>Add lab test</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Result</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <textarea class="form-control autosize" name="c" id="c"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">HIDDEN ID</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="a" id="a" value="<?php echo $a;   ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div> <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div> <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div> <!-- /.modal -->
```

I've took the advice of wrapping the form from the content/body but still no luck, it isn't proceeding to the designated action.

Here is the button to trigger the modal

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <a  data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Add Lab Test</a>
</div>
```

Even if I remove the `<form></form>` tags it still redirecting to the index.php

Comment: Format your code properly please, it's very hard to tell what it's doing here.

Comment: But that is the modal itself, I don't know how to format it more properly.

Comment: Just sort out your indentation, it's not difficult.

Comment: @DavidG I've just sorted my indention and cleared some stuff

Comment: Now see how it looks if you arrange it properly :)

Comment: Nothing happened, it just took me to my index.php

Comment: I mean, see how the question looks to people on here. Now it's possible to actually read it.

Comment: Thank you for the concern :)

Comment: Well, it should be yours and not mine, but it's done now. Anyway, what URL is being called by the submit exactly? Are you sure that exists on the server?

Comment: It is redirecting to the `index.php` but i didn't set that up or in my other projects, normally this code works. And yes the action is existing.

Comment: I suspect it is going to `site/folder/actions/add_lab_test.php` which doesn't exist though. Perhaps you need to prefix the form action with a `/`?

Comment: It is existing, what I do not understand is why THAT code is working on my previous project.

Comment: I would suggest to look first into your browser's developer tool and check for any console errors particularly JavaScript errors. If no errors, post the php script inside the `site/folder/actions/add_lab_test.php`?

Comment: @Ian There is no JavaScript errors, I'm suspecting that I missed to include some css files. But the fact that the modal is opening up defeats my suspicion

Comment: @Noobster not just the css but also the JS files (jquery.js, bootstraps.js).