# Bootstrap form data not submitting when in modal

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have the following form:

[image]

```html
<form action="../util/vcput.php" method="POST">
    <input name="vockey" type="hidden" value="<?php echo getCsrfToken(); ?>">
    <input name="a" value="addorgadmin" type="hidden">
    <input name="m" value="editorg" type="hidden">
    <input name="q1" value="orgid=<?php echo $org->id; ?>&orgadmins=1" type="hidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="orgid" value="<?php echo $org->id; ?>">
    <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email" id="userEmail" name="userEmail" aria-label="New Admin Email"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name" id="userName" name="userName" aria-label="New Admin Name"></input>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add admin</button> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add admin</button>
</form>
```

However, when clicking the submit button nothing happens, no data is submitted/no action is taken. I know that the name/id values are correct, as the lines are copied over from an older version of the page (modified to bootstrap v5).

Am I doing something wrong here? The form is in in a modal-body and doesn't work, but works when outside.

EDIT: Figured it out... I had a form tag enclosing the entire page that I had forgotten about, so having this form nested was breaking functionality. Oops.

Comment: Usually you're supposed to just post the code and not an image but I'll still try. Bootstrap should not be affecting submitting a form; is there any console error or anything? Is nothing submitting? Does anything happen when you click on the submit button?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The form submits fine when I test it.

Comment: @AlonEitan I added the code sorry. I just find the manual formatting extremely tedious, copy/paste constantly breaks formatting

Comment: @JohnDoe As far as I can tell absolutely nothing happens, there is no console output, and the backend php function is never called according to logs

Comment: @Quentin I've found that the issue seems to be specifically related to it being within a modal-body element, it submits when not in a modal. I can't figure out why

Comment: Is the submit button inside the form when the form is inside the modal? If not then give the form an `#id` and then add `form`  attribute with the `#id` as it's value to the button.

Comment: @zer00ne It is inside the form, seems the user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686089/form-submit-button-not-working-in-bootstrap-modal-window) is having the same issue. I'm testing out the JS solutions on that post but so far no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... I had a form tag enclosing the entire page that I had forgotten about, so having this form nested was breaking functionality. Oops.